# error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AccessManager.loginError'

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity выдаёт следующую ошибку: `Assets\Scripts\Sync\AccessManager.cs(17,33): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AccessManager.loginError'`

Вот сам код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AccessManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> loginError = new List<GameObject>();

    public static void CheckPerms(string devid)
    {
        if (devid == "dev1")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/Home Menu");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < loginError.Count; i++) \\тут ошибка
                loginError[i].SetActive(true); \\и ещё тут
            Debug.Log("0x02: AccessManager.cs: " + devid + " is not permitted");
        }
    }
}
```

Сам код сверяет введённый идентификатор пользователя с необходимым и выдаёт ошибку, если он не совпадает.
`for` в `else` активирует объекты на сцене. Если сделать `loginError` статиком, то он перестаёт быть `SerializedField`, а если с `void CheckPerms` снять статика, то будет ошибка в другом скрипте. Можете предложить решение этой проблемы, пожалуйста?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Только сейчас увидел, на выходных мб проверю

Comment: Ура, помогло! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала уберите `static` у метода `CheckPerms`.

Снаружи обращайтесь к экземпляру, например:

```
var manager = GetComponent<AccessManager>(); // или другой способ поиска объекта, смотря на чём висит скрипт и откуда вы к нему обращаетесь
manager.CheckPerms(...);
```

Суть ошибки в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к полю экземпляра из статического метода. C# же не знает, к какому именно экземпляру класса вы хотите обратиться, и выдаёт ошибку компиляции.